Can we honoured Intent flag value over Manifest in launch mode when intent flag and manifest launch mode is different?
Android Documentation mentioned for Same Intent Flag and Manifest Launch Mode but what when they are different?
So, if Activity A starts Activity B, Activity B can define in its manifest how it associates with the current task, and Activity A can use an intent flag to request how Activity B can associate with current task.
If both activities define how Activity B associates with a task, then Activity A's request, as defined in the intent, is honored over Activity B's request, as defined in its manifest.
when Activity B can define in its manifest how it associates with the current task is different(single Top) , and Activity A can use an intent flag to request how Activity B can associate with current task is different example(new task).
what will be honored over whom?

When both the manifest launch mode and the intent flags are defined but conflict, the intent flags from the calling activity (Activity A) generally take precedence over the launch mode defined in the manifest of the target activity (Activity B).
Example Scenario
Activity B Manifest: Defines singleTop as the launch mode.
Activity A Intent Flags: Specifies FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when launching Activity B.
What Happens?
Intent Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: This flag requests that Activity B should be launched in a new task.
Manifest singleTop: This specifies that if an instance of Activity B is already at the top of the task's back stack, it should be reused (no new instance should be created).
Precedence and Behavior:
Intent Flags Precedence: In this case, the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag will be honored over the singleTop launch mode defined in Activity B's manifest. Activity B will be launched in a new task, and the singleTop behavior will not apply.
Outcome: Activity B will start in a new task, regardless of whether an instance of Activity B already exists in the current task. The singleTop launch mode would only be relevant if FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK was not specified.
Key Takeaway:
When there is a conflict between the intent flags specified by the calling activity and the launch mode defined in the manifest, the intent flags specified by the calling activity (Activity A) typically take precedence.
